# Adding map to a list changes all maps in list to the latest map's values

Tags: list, flutter, syntax, maps

I'm trying to add a favorites functionality to my app and when the user selects the item, the item details are added to a List of Maps where each map has the details of the chosen item.

I thought this would be a simple system to implement, but I am clearly doing something wrong - I'm also fairly new to dart - sorry if its a stupid syntax problem. Any help would be appreciated, here is my code:

```
class FavoriteServices{
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> favoritesList = [{}];
  Map<String, dynamic> favoriteMap = {};

  void addFavoriteItemNEW(
      String objectID,
      String name,
      String author,
      String publisher,
      String price,
      String condition,
      String image,
  ) {
    favoriteMap["objectID"] = objectID;
    print(favoriteMap);
    favoritesList.add(favoriteMap);
    print(favoritesList);
    }
}
```

The values of the last added map will then be the values for all the maps before it as well. So it would seem like a duplication of the latest map for the length of the list. I'm sure it something silly, but I've been struggling with it for a while now.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

### TLDR;

Changing the scope of `favoriteMap` to the `addFavoriteItemNEW` should fix it.

```
  void addFavoriteItemNEW(
      String objectID,
      String name,
      String author,
      String publisher,
      String price,
      String condition,
      String image,
  ) {
    Map<String, dynamic> favoriteMap = {};
    favoriteMap["objectID"] = objectID;
    print(favoriteMap);
    favoritesList.add(favoriteMap);
    print(favoritesList);
    }
}
```

### But what's really happening?

Dart uses **Call by Reference** for `Map`

Take a look at this.

```
ain() {
  Map a = {"test": "test"};
  Map b = a;
  a["test"] = "test2";
  print(b); // Prints {"test": "test2"};
}
```

But we did not edit `b`, so what happened?.

Anytime You use a `Map` object somewhere, no matter where You change its properties (in the same scope), it'll get updated everywhere it was used.

The same thing is happening in Your case:
Because You keep adding `favoriteMap`(which lifecycle is in the class) to the list, anytime You change any of its properties, it changes for every occurrence of `favoriteMap` in the list.

Comment: Thank you so much! I definitely need to consider what the scope of my variables are next time